# something wrong with calculation code?

Tags: java, if-statement

this code is supposed to recieve two integers and an operation and then calculate the numbers. this is only part of the entire program everything else works but the calculations are wrong. The only correct output that i get when i run the whole thing is the subtraction. Whats wrong with it?

```
public static double calculate(int operand1, int operand2, char operation)
    { 
        if (operation=='^')
        {
            return (Math.pow(operand1,operand2));
         }
        else if(operation=='+')
        {
            return ((operand1)+(operand2));
        }
        else if(operation=='-')
        {
            return (operand1-operand2);
        }
        else if(operation=='*')
        {
            return (operand1*operand2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (operand2==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Cant divide by zero");
            }

            return(operand1/operand2);
        }

    }
```

---

Here is the entire code for the program

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Calculator 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    printIntro();
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String answer = "yes"; 
    while (answer.equals("yes"))  
{ 
 System.out.println("Enter your problem");
 String fullExpression=kb.nextLine(); 
 fullExpression=fullExpression.replaceAll("\\s","");
 int length=fullExpression.length();
 char op1=fullExpression.charAt(0);
 char op2=fullExpression.charAt(1);
 String operation=fullExpression.substring(2,length);
 printEnglish(op1,op2,operation);
 System.out.println("Type yes to continue");
 Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
 answer=kb1.nextLine();

}; 
} 


/*this methods gets the operands and the operation and 
prints the English version: if we call this method 
printEnglish(2,3, plus), then this method will output: 
Two plus three = 5 */ 
public static void printEnglish(char op1, char op2, String operation)  
{ 

 String resultOp1CharToString=charToString(op1);

 String resultOp2CharToString=charToString(op2);  
 char resultOperationConversion=operationConversion(operation);
 double resultCalculate=calculate(op1, op2, resultOperationConversion); 
 System.out.print(resultOp1CharToString+ operationConversion(operation) + resultOp2CharToString+ "=" + resultCalculate); 

    /*1. call the method charToString(op1) to convertlish 
    word for example ‘1’ to one or ‘2’ to two,…. 
    2. call the method operandConversionToNumber(op1) to 
    get its numeric value. For example if op1 is ‘1’ then 
    this method call should return the integer value 1 
    3. call the method operationConversion(operation) to 
    convert the operation to a mathematical operation. For 
    example if you call this method with the string plus 
    then it will return ‘+’ 
    4. finally call the method calculate to get the result 
    of the operation.*/
} 


/*this method prints the numeric version which is 2 *3 
=6*/
//public static boolean printNumeric(char op1, char op2, String operation)  
//{ 
 /*String resultCharToString=charToString(op1);
 String resultCharToString2=charToString(op2);  
 int resultOperandToNumber=operandConversionToNumber(op1);
 int resultOperandToNumber2=operandConversionToNumber(op2);
 char resultOperationConversion=operationConversion(operation);
 double resultCalculate=calculate(op1, op2, operation); */  

//} 


/*this method gets a number as a character and returns 
its numeric value as an integer. You must use case 
statement for this method*/ 
public static int operandConversiontoNumber(char operand) 
{ 
    int numberOperand=0;
    switch(operand)
    {
        case '0':
            numberOperand=0;
            break;
        case '1':
            numberOperand=1;
            break;
        case '2':
            numberOperand=2;
            break;
        case '3':
            numberOperand=3;
            break;
        case '4':
            numberOperand=4;
            break;
        case '5':
            numberOperand=5;
            break;
        case '6':
            numberOperand=6;
            break;
        case '7':
            numberOperand=7;
            break;
        case '8':
            numberOperand=8;
            break;
        case '9':
            numberOperand=9;
            break;
    }
    return numberOperand;

} 


/*this method gets the operation as a string and 
return the equivalent operation in math. For example 
if it receives “plus” the it will return ‘+’ */ 
public static char operationConversion(String s) 
{ 
    char operation=0;
    if(s.equals("plus"))
    {
        operation= '+';
    }

    else if(s.equals("minus"))
    {
        operation= '-';
    }

    else if(s.equals("multiply"))
    {
        operation= '*';
    }

    else if(s.equals("divide"))
    {
        operation= '/';
    }
    else
    {
        operation= '^';
    }

    return operation;


} 



/*this method recives two numbers and the operation
and returns the result*/ 
public static double calculate(int operand1, int operand2, char operation)
{ 
    if (operation=='^')
    {
        return (Math.pow(operand1,operand2));
    }
    else if(operation=='+')
    {
        return ((operand1)+(operand2));
    }
    else if(operation=='-')
    {
        return (operand1-operand2);
    }
    else if(operation=='*')
    {
        return (operand1*operand2);
    }
    else
    {
        if (operand2==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Cant divide by zero");
        }

        return(operand1/operand2);
    }

} 


/*this method converst a number character to its 
English word for example if this method receives ‘1’ 
it will return “one” */ 
public static String charToString(char num) 
{           

    String englishOperand="one";
    switch(num)
    {
        case '0':
            englishOperand= "zero";
            break;
        case '1':
            englishOperand="one";
            break;
        case '2':
            englishOperand="two";
            break;
        case '3':
            englishOperand="three";
            break;
        case '4':
            englishOperand= "four";
            break;
        case '5':
            englishOperand= "five";
            break;
        case '6':
            englishOperand= "six";
            break;
        case '7':
            englishOperand= "seven";
            break;
        case '8':
            englishOperand= "eight";
            break;
        case '9':
            englishOperand= "nine";
            break;
    }
    return englishOperand;
        }


//this method prints the decription of this program. 
public static void printIntro() 
{ 
    System.out.println("This program is a calculator, you need to enter two");
    System.out.println("single digit numbers and an operation(plus, minus,");
    System.out.println("divide, multiply, power) and it outputs its numeric");
    System.out.println("and English version. Your operand and operation can be");
    System.out.println("separated by space(s) or there could be no spaces"); 
    System.out.println("between them. For example you can enter “23plus” or “2 3 plus”"); 

}
```

}

I entered 2 3 plus and i expect 5 but i dont recieve that, but when i enter 2 3 minus i recieve -1

Comment: You need to provide more code. Where are you calling `calculate`?

Comment: In what way are the results wrong? What did you expect, what is the actual result, and how do these differ?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong ? sample input / expected output ?

Comment: You have a logic error, but it doesn't match the symptom you describe (to the extent you describe a symptom): If you try `/`, you'll get an error, because although you check for `operand2==0`, you still go ahead and try to divide with it.

Comment: I'd use `switch` instead of all these ifs. Also, can you give an example when this code doesn't produce expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (operand2==0)
{
    System.out.println("Cant divide by zero");
    return -1; // some dummy value
}
else
{
    return(operand1/operand2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Division will be incorrect as it's doing integer division and you want a double result. It will also throw a divide by zero error because you don't return.

```
if (operand2 == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Cant divide by zero");
    return 0; // I guess
}
return (double)operand1 / (double)operand2;
```

All the rest look like they should work fine.